# Getting "reason": "RESOURCE:PORTS" when running Jenkins build

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

when I run a Jenkins build, my back-end code is not updating in AWS. There seems to be an error when I try to build the Elastic Beanstalk:

```
Encountered error starting new ECS task: { "failures": [ { "reason": "RESOURCE:PORTS", "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:863820595425:container-instance/d6b92955-eb16-4911-b874-683155fcd630" } ], "tasks": [] }
```

Has anyone encountered this before? The port set up in the dockerrun.aws.json file has not been changed in over a year. If I manually restart Task Definitions this backend will eventually update but I need to see why the Ports issue is happening.

My dockerrrun.aws.json file:

```
 {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "customerportal-backend",
      "image": "<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<ECR_REPO_NAME>:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 1024,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 3001
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
        "sourceVolume": "store-efs",
        "containerPath": "/efs-mount-point"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        "clamav-rest"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "clamav-server",
      "image": "mkodockx/docker-clamav:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 1536
    },
    {
      "name": "clamav-rest",
      "image": "lokori/clamav-rest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 1024,
      "links": [
        "clamav-server:clamav-server"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 3100,
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "environment" : [
          { "name" : "CLAMD_HOST", "value" : "clamav-server" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name" : "store-efs",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/efs"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```